# Excel - Index Match formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Here what I have `=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(G2,N:N,0))` but i know this wrong

I want to match by player name, team, wOBA ,Iso from left side (columns A-I) to the right side (columns N - Q). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have a *question*? This isn't a code (or formula) writing service.

Comment: You already know you need an INDEX/MATCH, what  formula did you try?  What is it doing that is incorrect?

Comment: Here what I have =INDEX(C:C,MATCH(G2,N:N,0)) but i know this wrong

Comment: You have the columns reversed: `=INDEX(N:N,MATCH(G2,C:C,0))`

Comment: @ScottCraner - even your formula fails. it's really not clear what the user wants to index from, but perhaps it's get the team based on column N and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your pictures that you want to get TEAM, wOBA, iso from the name in column N.

If so, do this:

```
=INDEX(B:B,Match(N2,$C:$C,0))
```

then adjust for other columns.

If that is not your exact need, you can certainly see how this one works and modify as needed.

You could also get fancy and use one formula to drag through all your data set:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$I$9,MATCH($N2,$C$1:$C$9,0),MATCH(O$1,$A$1:$I$1,0))
```